# CMS page not found

Tags: cms, 404, routing

I have a strange error.

I created a new CMS page with url `mtclp/20` and got an error page 404.

If I change url on just lps, it works. If I try with, for example, test/30, It also works. Other pages also works.

Magento does not like only the combination mtclp/20.

We do not have this url anywhere. I cleaned cash and tried to search by global search this combination in project.

Comment: Hi, have you looked in Marketing -> URL Rewrites if it's there at all?

Comment: Don't use / in cms page url. This is not recommended

Comment: Thank you for the answers.  In URL Rewrites everything is all right. No this URL. I must use url, because it is an old project, and other CMS pages work correctly. I can just change URL, but  this bug may occur elsewhere

Comment: I just created cms page url with lps/30 its working fine in magento 1.9.3.9 so might be you have any URL Rewrite there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. The problem is that in magento in cms url is impossible to use `lp/` (in our configuration). Because:

in method `_rewriteConfig()`,
path:  `app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Url\Rewrite\Request.php`

```
Logger::log("from: ".$from, "Log");
Logger::log("to: ".$to, "Log");
Logger::log("pathInfo before: ".$this->_request->getPathInfo(), "Log");
$pathInfo = preg_replace($from, $to, $this->_request->getPathInfo());
Logger::log("pathInfo: ".$pathInfo, "Log");
```

If we look on the log file, we become:

- from: /lp/(.*)/
- to: lp/index/index/$1
- pathInfo before: /mtclp/20
- pathInfo: /mtclp/index/index/20

`lp/` is replaced with `lp/indx/index/$1`